# TokenMismatchException with javascript x-editable on Laravel 5.3

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

Before marking it as duplicated, i tried the other solutions found on the web, including SO, and none of them solved my issue.

I'm using [x-editable](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html#editable) plugin to store a new record using a store route.

When the form is submitted, i get a 500 with TokenMismatchException error.

I know about setting the **csrf token** thing, but i tried it in several ways, and nothing is working.

That's my *javascript* code:

```
$.fn.editable.defaults.params = function (params) {
    params._token = window.Laravel.csrfToken;
    return params;
};
$('.editable').each(function () {
    $(this).editable();
});
```

The *html*

```
<head>
    [...]
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    [...]
    <script>
        window.Laravel = <?php
        echo json_encode([
            'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
        ]);
        ?>
    </script>
    [...]
</head>

<button id="note-asl-text"
    data-type="textarea"
    data-placeholder="Aggiungi Nota"
    data-url="{{route('ricettanota.store')}}"
    data-title="Inserisci una nuova nota"
    data-highlight="false"
    data-mode="inline"
    data-send="always"
    data-showbuttons="bottom"
    class="editable"
    >Aggiungi nota</button>
```

The *Route*

```
Route::resource('ricettanota', 'RicettaNotaController');
```

---

I already tried all possible combinations of the following:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': window.Laravel.csrfToken
    }
});

$('.editable').each(function () {
    $(this).editable({
        ajaxOptions: {contentType: 'application/json', dataType: 'json'},
        params: function (params) {
            params._token = window.Laravel.csrfToken;
            return JSON.stringify(params);
        }
    });
});
```

**note**

`$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')` and `window.Laravel.csrfToken` are the same

[image: See request screenshot]

---

**update**

I found out that placing `Route::resource('ricettanota', 'RicettaNotaController');` into the api routes file(*api.php*) causes the issue, while placing the routes into the web routes file (*web.php*) and using the code above works.

Why using the API i get token mismatch, is still a mystery.

Comment: Did include token in header

Comment: @MohamedAthif yes, i wrote it in the question.

Comment: I mean in the head of html too.  Not just Javascript

Comment: Yes, i just updated the question adding the head of html

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but maybe you should not struggling in sending custom header with x-editable plugin, but sending custom parameters.

The following code works for me.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'popup';     
    $('.node').editable(
        {
            params: function(params) {
                var data = {};
                data['_csrf_token'] = $(this).data("csrf");
                return data;
            },
        }
    );
});
```

Set csrf in your a-tag or somewhere else you like.

```
<a href="#" ... data-csrf="xxxxxxx" /a>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your ajaxSetup

```
$.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
```

Comment: already tried, `$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')` and `window.Laravel.csrfToken` are the same

Comment: why don't you try console.log the token, if it is being called by the javascript?

Comment: I don't get your point, but console.log of token works. I do have the token in the request, but i get anyway token mismatch

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same issue in Laravel 5.8. Following code worked for me.

```
$.fn.editable.defaults.ajaxOptions = {
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

this is use code

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: url,
headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
dataType:'html',
data:data,
success:function(data){

}});
```

this Follow link

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token

Comment: I know about it, but i can't call a custom `$.ajax`